# Iterating multiple items from list in MVC C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, foreach, partial-views

I am not sure how to do this in MVC, in normal code I would just iteratre in my loop and write the item, but I am lost doing this in MVC. In this program I am reading RSS feed from World of Warcraft site.
I've got this method:

```
public ActionResult Bar()
{
    List<string> temat = new List<string>();
    List<string> podpis = new List<string>();
    List<DateTime> czas = new List<DateTime>();
    string url = "http://eu.battle.net/wow/en/feed/news";
    using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(url))
    {
        SyndicationFeed feed = SyndicationFeed.Load(reader);

        foreach (SyndicationItem item in feed.Items)
        {
            String subject = item.Title.Text;
            String summary = item.Summary.Text;
            DateTime date = item.PublishDate.DateTime;

            temat.Add(subject);
            podpis.Add(summary);
            czas.Add(czasy);
        }
    }
    reader.Close();
    ViewBag.tytul = temat;
    ViewBag.opis = podpis;
    ViewBag.c = czas;
    return PartialView("_Bar");
}
```

And in my partialView I can get to each item from ViewBag like this:

```
<div class="row">
    @foreach (var o in ViewBag.opis)
    {
        <p>@Html.Raw(@o)</p>
    }
</div>
```

But I need to iterate like this:

> "item1" from "list1" => "item1" from "list2" => "item1" from "list3"
>   => "item2" from "list1" => ETC...

I don't know how to do this in this View, can someone help me?

Comment: What do you mean _"in normal code"_? And what is `ViewBag.opis`? and which lists do you mean?

Comment: @StephenMuecke Of course I forgot to add viewbags. Sorry. VieBag.opis is list<podpis> which contains summary items. By "normal code" I mean code in C#, in my foreach loop, and not in a view. I am not native speaker so it might be called different.

Comment: For me it looks like You should go with model not with ViewBag. You can iterate throughout viewbag but You need to cast it to some type - it's a dynamic Type - type resolved at runtime. So You can iterate but You got no intelisense for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, You need to create a class for it because Your approach makes no sense.
Let's create a class:

```
public class MyModel
{
  public string Topic { get; set; }
  public string Signature { get; set; }
  public DateTime Time { get; set; }
}
```

Later on let's change Your Controller to this:

```
public ActionResult Bar()
{
    List<MyModel> _model = new List<MyModel>();
    using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(url))
    {
        SyndicationFeed feed = SyndicationFeed.Load(reader);

        foreach (SyndicationItem item in feed.Items)
        {
            var newItem = new MyModel();
            newItem.Topic = item.Title.Text;
            newItem.Signature = item.Summary.Text;
            newItem.Time = item.PublishDate.DateTime;

            _model.Add(newItem);
        }
    }
    return PartialView("_Bar", _model); 
}
```

Now You have strongly typed model in Your View so just add a namespace on top(lets assume MyModel is in the xxx.Models namespace):

```
@model  IEnumerable <xxx.Models.MyModel>
```

Now You can iterate throughout this with intellisense liek this:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <p>item.Topic</p>
    <p>item.Signature</p>
    <p>item.Time</p>
}
```

Comment: Remember - use ViewBag only if You want to pass some little extra data. Model approach is much better !(that's why it's called Model-View-Controller not ViewBag-View-Controller)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, build a new class that will hold your data.

```
Class WOWClass
{
    public string temat {get;set;}
    public DateTime czas {get;set;}
}
```

Then populdate a list of WOWClass instead of 3 lists...

```
public ActionResult Bar()
{
    List<WOWClass> list = new List<WOWClass>();
    string url = "http://eu.battle.net/wow/en/feed/news";
    using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(url))
    {
        SyndicationFeed feed = SyndicationFeed.Load(reader);

        foreach (SyndicationItem item in feed.Items)
        {
            //populate your list
        }
    }
    return PartialView("_Bar", list);
}
```

And finally this is the view:

```
<div class="row">
    @foreach (var o in Model)
    {
        Temat: <p>@Html.Raw(o.temat)</p>
        Czas: <p>@Html.Raw(o.czas)</p>
    }
</div>
```

Comment: Haven't tested the code, becuase I am away, but I like this idea!

Comment: This should Throw an exception ... calling Close on Disposed XmlReader, which anyway - isn't even accesible outside the using statement.

Comment: And You no longer need this ViewBags